# check connection from C# app to oracle 10g database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, database-connection

How can I check connection from C# app to oracle 10g database?

For example I have Oracle server on machine with IP 10.50.65.2. I maintain IP, Port in app.config.

I move app to another pc connected to another network. I need  check if it is possible create  correct connection with database server.

If it is not possible create db connection I need 
show only simple message please modify db connection data in app.config.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just try to create the connection and catch the exception if it fails?

Perhaps something like this:

```
public bool CheckConnection()
{
    string connectionString = ""; //Get from configuraiton.
    using(var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If connection is killed on server it will return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

This worked for me on Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

try something like this maybe?

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnction(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
try{
    conn.Open();
catch(Exception){
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Please modify db connection data in app.config.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The oracle Connection has a .Open

so you would do something like this

```
 if (conn.State  == OracleConnection.Open)
    {  
           //connection is already open
    }
    else 
    {
        //connection is in another state and can be used
    }
```

Mind you I am assuming that you know your state since you are using a static ip and such defined in your app.config.  Otherwise I would say [Chris's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475233/check-connection-from-c-app-to-oracle-10g-database/7475253#7475253) will work if you do not have a singleton holding your connection to the DB.