# Checking oracle connection

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, timeout, connection-string

I'm seriously stuck here with something obvious. 
I have an application that communicates with Oracle and MSSQL servers.

Both of them build their connection strings and then

```
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        } catch ...
```

Now if i will enter wrong server name, SQL Server connection will timeout and i will happily handle an exception. But Oracle connection in C# does not seem to support timeout, so i will be never back from connection.Open() and my application will hang.

I found somewhat similar question, but it's not it, because answer is the same to what i'm doing and doesn't work.

[check connection from C# app to oracle 10g database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475233/check-connection-from-c-sharp-app-to-oracle-10g-database)

Is it some weird bug or i should check my Oracle libs? Speaking of which OracleConnection is obsolete, should i use something else maybe(though i'd rather not)

So the thing i need is a way to handle wrong server name as easily as possible.

Edit 1: Now what i thought of till now was running connection.Open() in different thread and killing it on timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [third party library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) as per [Microsoft's recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx).

Comment: @noaRAVE Best way to connect to Oracle from C# that I know is using the ODAC (Oracle data access components) for .Net, available from Oracle corps. It has it's own share of problems (surmountable though).

Comment: i still wish i could keep using OracleConnection, since i have a lot of other code with it in a project.